# Setting camera and frustum parameters in VTK

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, vtk

I am rendering a mesh model in VTK as follows:

```
string mesh_filename = "mesh.ply";

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYReader> mesh_reader = read_mesh_ply(mesh_filename);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(mesh_reader->GetOutputPort());
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

renderWindow->SetSize(640, 480);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

//Add the actors to the scene
renderer->AddActor(actor);
renderer->SetBackground(1, 1, 1);
```

I am trying to set the camera by calling:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera>::New();
renderer->SetActiveCamera(camera);
camera->SetPosition(0, 650, 0);
```

and then render the scene by calling:

```
renderWindow->Render();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

The problem is, under this perspective projection the model is not showing at this viewpoint. I can get and set the near and far values of the frustum by calling:

```
double near, far;
camera->GetClippingRange(near, far);
near = 0.001;
far = 1000000;
camera->GetClippingRange(near, far);
```

But still the model is not showing. Do I need to change the top,bottom,left and right? If so how do I do this?

**EDIT:**

I have set the focal point, view up and position of camera as well as made the clipping range huge, still cannot see the object:

```
camera->SetFocalPoint(0,0,0);
camera->SetViewUp(0,1,0);
camera->SetPosition(0,650,0);

renderer->ResetCameraClippingRange(-10000,100000,-100000,100000,100000,0.0001);
```

Answer (score 4):

The camera's position is defined by its focal point, position, and up vector.  To view the model, you want to focal point to be near the model so the camera looks at it. If everything else is working, the camera may just be pointing in the wrong direction.

You can set the camera focus with overloads of the `vtkCamera` method `SetFocalPoint`.

You may also want to try the `vtkRenderer` method `ResetCamera()` which will modify the camera to view all visible actors.

Comment: I have used your suggestion (see Edit to question) but still cannot see the object. The camera is facing the origin, with up direction being the Y axis.

Comment: @Aly Are you able to confirm that the object is there by moving the camera around until you see it?

Comment: by scrolling and dragging with my mouse there is no change whatsoever. However, I just was experimenting, if I set the camera position to (0,650,1) it displays just fine. I initially thought this was a problem with the near plane being to close, so I changed the near clipping plane to 10 instead of 0.001 and set camera back to (0,650,0) and it does **not** display, so I don't think it's to do with the clipping plane

Comment: Drew perhaps the problem is with the ViewUP?

Comment: @AEDrew it appears as though it is a problem with the view Up direction. For example, if I do camera->setViewUp(0,0,1) and then camera->setPosition(0,0,650) it does not show, but camera->setPosition(0,1,650) and it does

Comment: @Aly I am guessing the problem is because you are setting the view up vector parallel to the view direction, which does not really make sense.  If the view direction is along, for example, the Z-axis, you want the view up to be perpendicular to the Z-axis (e.g. (1,0,0) or (0,1,0) etc.)).  The view up vector essentially rotates the camera around the view direction axis.  In your example above try: `camera->SetFocalPoint(0,0,0);camera->setPosition(0,0,650);camera->SetViewUp(0,1,0);`

Comment: @AEDrew yes you are correct. My problem is that I have points on a sphere and I move the camera from point to point. The question now is, how to update the Up vector. If I say at point (0,0,650) the up vector is (0,1,0) and then the new point may be (0,650,0) which is a 90 degree rotation, I must also rotate my Up vector? additionally, if my next coordinate is (600,450,0) for example, do I work out the rotation from (0,0,650) to (600,450,0) and then apply it to the original up vector of (0,1,0)?

Comment: @Aly If you stick to simple movements on a sphere I think the following should help: `Elevation(double angle)`, `Azimuth(double angle)`, and `OrthogonalizeViewUp ()`.